# Change SublimeREPL Execute Key Binding to cmd-enter in Sublime Text 3 (ST3)

Tags: r, sublimetext3, key-bindings, sublimerepl

In sublime text 2 I simply used `Enhanced-R` in order to use the cmd+enter hot key to evaluate a snippet of code in `SublimeREPL` or the native R app. As far as I can tell, this package doesn't exist for ST3. So, might I change the key binding, currently, control+,,l (control and comma, then l), to cmd+enter?

I imagine I need to modify the file found here: `Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > User` or `Preferences > Keybindings - User`, but am not sure which or what to add.

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [**`R-Box`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/R-Box). `Enhanced R` was rewritten some time ago as `R-Box`, both are by the same author - `R-Box` mainly has much extended functionality, including a new menu when `.R` files are active. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on other operating systems) should still work the same way. You'll have to redo your customized settings, of course, but all in all the new plugin is nicer and has many more features than the old one.

Comment: As an addendum, when exploring this option, it looks like there is some new functionality where you can select which device to send it to (ex. R gui, Rstudio or terminal).

More info here: https://github.com/randy3k/R-Box

"There is a huge change of R-Box in this Sublime Text 3 only version --- R-Box no longer ships with the "send code" functionality. R-Box will mainly focus on the R language development. The "send code" functionality is exported to SendTextPlus. You could choose the active program by the option SendTextPlus: Choose Program in command palette."